# PHP Session + MySQL resource

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to give a mysql resource to a $_SESSION variable ?

```
//mysqldb.inc.php
class mySqlDb
{
    private $link;

    public function __construct($_host = '', $_db = '', $_user = '', $_pwd = '')
    {
           $link = mysql_pconnect(...);
    }

    public function query($data)
    {
           $r = mysql_query($data, $this->link);
           return $r;
    }
}


//index.php
session_start();
include_once('mysqldb.inc.php');

$sqlobj = new mySqlDb();
$sqlobj->dbconnect($db_host, $db_name, $db_user, $db_pwd);
$_SESSION['mysqldb'] = $sqlobj;


//check.php
session_start();
include_once('mysqldb.inc.php');

$sqlobj = $_SESSION['mysqldb'];
$sqlobj->query(...);
```

`$sqlobj->query(...)` return

> Fatal error: main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "mySqlDb" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in D:\apache\www\check.php on line 4`

If I use `$_SESSION['mysqldb'] = serialize($sqlobj)` and `$sqlobj = unserialize($_SESSION['mysqldb'])` I have this error:

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, integer given in D:\apache\www\mysqldb.inc.php on line ...

Comment: I don't see why not. But why *would* you?

Comment: Also, it may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot persist php resources.

That's it - you just cannot. So you need to connect to database each time.

The [`$_SESSION` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) notes:

> Because session data is serialized, resource variables cannot be stored in the session.

Comment: Ok, so I will connect one time only and cache the data until they are valid.

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
$sqlobj = new mySqlDb();
```

But then you do this:

```
$_SESSION['mysqldb'] = $sql;
```

I.e. you're setting `$_SESSION['mysqldb']` to an object that doesn't exist. Try `$sqlobj` instead.